# ¿Cómo puedo agregar información desde la base de datos a mi archivo PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap, base-de-datos

Hace poco comencé a programar y ahora estoy terminando una página web (un blog para ser exacto) y no entiendo cómo mostrar la información como tarjetas en *Bootstrap 4*. Hasta el  momento tengo 4 entradas en mi base de datos (`id`, `nombre`, `fecha`, `link` e imagen).

Este es mi código:

```
<?php
echo'<div class="row d-flex">';
$count = 1;

while ($registroRecetas = $resRecetas->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
  extract($registroRecetas);

  echo'<div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
    <div class="card-group">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src='.$registroRecetas['portada'].' alt="Imagen de portada"> 
        <div class="card-block">
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">'.$registroRecetas['fecha'].'</h6>
          <h4 class="card-tittle">'.$registroRecetas['nombre'].'</h4>
          <a href='.$registroRecetas['link'].' class="card-link">Leer más</a>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
    </div>';
  if($count++ % 2 == 0){
    echo'</div>';
  }
}
?>
```

Mi mayor problema es que los 2 primeros post se muestran bien, pero el tercero y ya el cuarto no aparecen como los 2 primeros, aparecen uno debajo del otro a la izquierda.

Actualmente lo veo así:

```
4 - 3
2 
1
```

Me gustaría que las tarjetas se vieran así:

```
4 - 3
2 - 1
```

Y cuando vaya agregando más información a la base de datos, estos vayan bajando ordenadamente.

¿Como puedo hacer que todas las tarjetas aparezcan de forma ordenada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El  error puede ser que al momento de validar que `$count` sea `par` , cierras el `<div class="row d-flex">` pero luego no hay forma de que se vuelva a abrir para añadir los siguientes dos elementos dentro de otro `div` con las mismas clases `"row d-flex"`

Más bien lo que haces es que después de los dos primeros elementos , los siguientes elementos se añaden a un `<div class="col-md-6 d-flex">`  y se muestran como elementos únicos.

para solucionar después de cerrar el el `div` en el `if` , volver a crear otro `div` con la clases ''

```
if($count++ % 2 == 0){
    echo'</div>';
    echo'<div class="row d-flex">';
}
```

Comment: No puedo creer que la respuesta era tan simple, un millón de gracias!!!!